# how to get years last week record when week end in next year

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to get record of years last week when week is end in next year
for example I have to get record of following four week where week 53 is end in 2016 .

```
week_no  week_start  -   week_end 
==================================
week-53 (2015-12-28 to 2016-01-03) 
week-52 (2015-12-21 to 2015-12-27) 
week-51 (2015-12-14 to 2015-12-20) 
week-50 (2015-12-07 to 2015-12-13)
```

and following is my query

```
function getLastFourWeekUser($table=FALSE){        
    if($table==TRUE){
        $this->db->from($table);
    }
    else{
        $this->db->from('users');        
    }        
    $endDate=date('Y-m-d',  strtotime('-3 week'));        
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $year=date('Y',strtotime($endDate));
    $week=date('W',strtotime($endDate));
    $week_start = $dto->setISODate($year,$week)->format('Y-m-d');        
    $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('o')-date('W')-7));                  
    $query = $this->db->select('count(*) as count,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%u-%Y") as week',false)                                        
                      ->where('created_at >=',$week_start)  
                      ->where('created_at <=',$to)
                      ->group_by('week')
                      ->order_by('week')
                      ->get();
    }
```

I wrote a query which will give me record of only this year i.e. till 2015-12-31
only.
But I want records of 1st-jan to 3rd-jan too.
Because week 53 ends in 2016-01-03.

Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: not sure but it happen beacuse you used date('o') in $to and set : 'created_at <=',$to   where created at consider 2015 year so it not be able to go in 2016

Comment: Yes, you right,but if i write ('Y') instead of ('o') than it give me result as week-0.

Comment: use turnery operator and set condition in $to = (if condition ?)if week completed in past year use this(put your logic) : if in same year use another(put your logic) ;

Comment: but i think so every time last week should end in next year

Comment: try using $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y')-date('W')-7)); it will give you current year result or use it like $to = (condition)? date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('O')-date('W')-7)): date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y')-date('W')-7));

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%x%v'), 'Monday'), '%x%v%W'), '%Y-%m-%d'), "%u-%Y") AS week,
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%x%v'), 'Monday'), '%x%v%W'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS week_start,
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%x%v'), 'Sunday'), '%x%v%W'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS week_end,
COUNT(*) as count
WHERE created_at >='$week_start' AND created_at <='$to'
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week
```

Comment: it gives me record still 31-12-2015

Comment: `$to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('o')-date('W')-7));` by this contruction you want to get last date of current week?

Comment: than `$to = new \DateTime(); $to = $to->add(new \DateInterval('P'.(7-$to->format('N')).'D'))->format('Y-m-d');`